# Validate a course code using a method in java

Tags: java, class, validation, methods, numbers

I have to get my course code to validate.  The course code is set to a number 1-7  and the choice has to be within this range.  Each course is worth 3 credits.  The user can not register for more than 9 credits.  The user can not register for the same course more than once.  I am having trouble with the repeat course code.

Here is my code:

```
package u6a1_consoleregisterforcourse;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class U6A1_ConsoleRegisterForCourse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           
        System.out.println("Quenten's Copy");
                
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //choice is the current menu selection
        //firstChoice is the first menu selection mande by the user
        //secondChoice is the second menu selection mande by the user
        //thirdChoice is the third menu selection mande by the user
        // a choice of 0 means the choice has not been made yet
        int choice;
        int firstChoice = 0, secondChoice = 0, thirdChoice = 0;
        int totalCredit = 0;
        String yesOrNo = "";

        
        do {

            choice = getChoice(input);
            
            switch (ValidateChoice(choice, firstChoice, secondChoice, thirdChoice, totalCredit)) {
                case -1:
                    System.out.println("**Invalid** - Your selection of " + choice + " is not a recognized course.");
                    break;
                case -2:
                    System.out.println("**Invalid** - You have already registerd for this " +  ChoiceToCourse(choice) + " course.");
                    break;
                case -3:
                    System.out.println("**Invalid** - You can not register for more than 9 credit hours.");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Registration Confirmed for course " + ChoiceToCourse(choice) );
                    totalCredit += 3;
                    if (firstChoice == 0)
                        firstChoice = choice;
                    else if (secondChoice == 0)
                        secondChoice = choice;
                    else if (thirdChoice == 0)
                        thirdChoice = choice;
                    break;
            }

            WriteCurrentRegistration(firstChoice, secondChoice, thirdChoice);
            
            System.out.print("\nDo you want to try again? (Y|N)? : ");
            
            yesOrNo = input.next().toUpperCase();
            
        } while (yesOrNo.equals("Y"));

        System.out.println("Thank you for registering with us");
        
    }


    public static int getChoice(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("Please type the number inside the [] to register for a course");
        System.out.println("[1]IT4782\n[2]IT4784\n[3]IT4786\n[4]IT4789\n[5]IT2230\n[6]IT3345\n[7]IT3349");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
        return (input.nextInt());
    
    }
 
    //This method validates the user menu selection
    //against the given registration business rules
    //it returns the following code based on the validation result
    // -1 = invalid, unrecognized menu selection
    // -2 = invalid, alredy registered for the course
    // -3 = invalid, No more than 9 credit hours allowed
    // 0 = menu selection is valid
    public static int ValidateChoice(int choice, int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice, int totalCredit) {
      
        // TO DO - Add Code to:
        // Validate user menu selection (the int choice method argument)
        // against the given registration business rules
        int ValidateChoice;
        
        if ((choice < 1) || (choice >= 8)){
            ValidateChoice = -1;}
        else if (secondChoice == firstChoice){
            ValidateChoice = -2;}
        
      
        
        else
        {ValidateChoice = 0;}
        
        
        
        
        return ValidateChoice;
                
    }
    
    public static void WriteCurrentRegistration(int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice) {

        if (firstChoice == 0)
            System.out.println("Current course registration:  { none } " );     
        else if (secondChoice == 0)
            System.out.println("Current course registration: { " + ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice) + " }" );
        else if (thirdChoice == 0)
            System.out.println("Current course registration: { " + ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice) + 
                    ", " + ChoiceToCourse(secondChoice) + " }");
        else
            System.out.println("Current course registration: { " + ChoiceToCourse(firstChoice) + 
                    ", " + ChoiceToCourse(secondChoice) + ", " + ChoiceToCourse(thirdChoice) + " }");
    }

    public static String ChoiceToCourse(int choice) {
            String course = "";
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    course = "IT4782";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    course = "IT4784";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    course = "IT4786";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    course = "IT4789";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    course = "IT2230";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    course = "IT3345";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    course = "IT3349";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return course;
    }
           
}
```

The ValidateChoice method is what I am working on. This is for an academic assignment.

Comment: You can put your input courses into an array and the check the duplicate course from that array.

Comment: Also you never check for anything equal to `thirdChoice` and I'm confused exactly what those variables are meant to represent.  What value do they take if no choice has been made yet?  Can the user change an existing choice?  How does that "compare"?

Comment: I haven't got to testing the thirdChoice. I was testing it to see if it would compare it and as i currently have it coded it does not.  We haven't got to arrays yet in class.  How would I put them into a string and compare them to the string?

Comment: I would say don't try a string.  I think you should change your main method to run explicit tests, exercising the validate method with different values, so you can test it quickly and efficiently.  Trying to enter all possible combinations by hand is hard and slow.

Comment: I agree that they are hard and slow but the assignment we have says that we have to do it in the validateCourse method.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to get rid of those `firstChoice`, `secondChoice`, `thirdChoice` variables and use a homogeneous collection instead:

```
package u6a1_consoleregisterforcourse;

import java.util.*;

public class U6A1_ConsoleRegisterForCourse {
    public static final int CREDITS_PER_COURSE = 3;
    public static final int MAX_CREDITS = 9;
    public static final int MAX_COURSES = MAX_CREDITS / CREDITS_PER_COURSE;
    private final List<Integer> registeredCourses = new ArrayList<>(MAX_COURSES);
    private int totalCredit;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Quenten's Copy");
        U6A1_ConsoleRegisterForCourse registrar = new U6A1_ConsoleRegisterForCourse();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //choice is the current menu selection
        int choice;
        String yesOrNo;
        do {
            choice = getChoice(input);
            switch (registrar.validateChoice(choice)) {
                case -1:
                    System.out.println("**Invalid** - Your selection of " + choice + " is not a recognized course.");
                    break;
                case -2:
                    System.out.println("**Invalid** - You have already registered for this " + choiceToCourse(choice) + " course.");
                    break;
                case -3:
                    System.out.println("**Invalid** - You can not register for more than " + MAX_CREDITS + " credit hours.");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Registration Confirmed for course " + choiceToCourse(choice));
                    registrar.totalCredit += CREDITS_PER_COURSE;
                    registrar.registeredCourses.add(choice);
                    break;
            }
            registrar.writeCurrentRegistration();
            System.out.print("\nDo you want to try again? (Y|N)? : ");
            yesOrNo = input.next().toUpperCase();
        } while (yesOrNo.equals("Y"));
        System.out.println("Thank you for registering with us");
    }

    private static final String[] courses = {"IT4782", "IT4784", "IT4786", "IT4789", "IT2230", "IT3345", "IT3349"};

    public static String choiceToCourse(int choice) {
        return courses[choice - 1];
    }

    public static int getChoice(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("Please type the number inside the [] to register for a course");
        for (int i = 1; i <= courses.length; i++)
            System.out.format("[%d]%s%n", i, choiceToCourse(i));
        System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
        return (input.nextInt());
    }

//    This method validates the user menu selection
//    against the given registration business rules
//    it returns the following code based on the validation result
//     -1 = invalid, unrecognized menu selection
//     -2 = invalid, alredy registered for the course
//     -3 = invalid, No more than 9 credit hours allowed
//     0 = menu selection is valid
    public int validateChoice(int choice) {
        if ((choice < 1) || (choice > courses.length))
            return -1;
        if (registeredCourses.contains(choice))
            return -2;
        if (totalCredit + CREDITS_PER_COURSE > MAX_CREDITS)
            return -3;
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeCurrentRegistration() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Current course registration: ");
        if (registeredCourses.isEmpty())
            sb.append(" { none }");
        else {
            sb.append("{ ");
            boolean first = true;
            for (int i : registeredCourses) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    sb.append(", ");
                sb.append(choiceToCourse(i));
            }
            sb.append(" }");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the parameters I was given, and only allowed to change the ValidateChoice method, I was able to take John McClane's answer and convert it to make it work.  I thank you for the help.  What I have done is simple and now makes sense.

Here it is:

```
public static int ValidateChoice(int choice, int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice, int totalCredit) {

    // TO DO - Add Code to:
    // Validate user menu selection (the int choice method argument)
    // against the given registration business rules
    
    
    if ((choice < 1) || (choice >7))
        return  -1;
    if ((choice == secondChoice) || (choice == firstChoice))
        return -2;
    if (totalCredit >= 9)
        return -3;
   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write 3 different validations in your code:

```
public static int ValidateChoice(int choice, int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice, int totalCredit) {

        //Validation: Choice is in range of 1 and 7
        if(choice > 7 || choice < 1){
            return -1;
            
        }

        // Validation : No 2 course choices have same value
        boolean isInvalid  = firstChoice!=0 ? 
        (firstChoice == secondChoice ||firstChoice == thirdChoice):
        (secondChoice!=0 && secondChoice==thirdChoice);

        if(isInvalid) {
          return -2;
        }
        // Validation : Total credits are not more than 9
        else if(totalCredit > 9){
            return -3;
        }
        else{
           return 0;  
        }
       
}
```

One of your fellow course mate have also asked this question here,

[Validating inputs in a function in java to avoid duplicate data other than non entry with default of 0 (No database )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295344/validating-inputs-in-a-function-in-java-to-avoid-duplicate-data-other-than-non-e/63297169#63297169)

Be careful of Plagiarism

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and provide and explanation to your source code, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer. Also, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)