# Validating inputs in a function in java to avoid duplicate data other than non entry with default of 0 (No database )

Tags: java, algorithm

I have three integer variable of which each has default value of 0. I want to update the values each to a value that is unique from the other. In case I try update two variable to same value I should be allowed by the validation. I am stuck on writing the validation part of the program. Please can anyone guide me?

```
 public static int ValidateChoice(int choice, int firstChoice, int secondChoice, int thirdChoice, int totalCredit) {

    // TO DO - Add Code to:
    // Validate user menu selection (the int choice method argument)
    /* against the given registration business rules below:
       No registration of other courses not displayed by the program
       No registration more than once for the same course
       No registration for more than 9 credit hours (e.g. no more than 3 
       courses)
      */    

    //by fact the choice are limited to seven option 
    //anything beyond seven or below 1 is considered invalid
    if(choice > 8 || choice < 0){
        return -1;
        
    }

    //my problem is from here

    ///No two courses chosen should be the same 
    //therefore blacklisting the inappropriate submission of course is  captured by the condition in the if
    // initial state thirdChoice=0 secondChoice=0 firstChoice=0
    else if((firstChoice==secondChoice || firstChoice== thirdChoice || secondChoice==thirdChoice)){
        
        return -2;
    }

   // upto here

    //the total credit for the course is upto 9 hours
    else if(totalCredit > 9) {
        return -3;
    }
    else {
       return 0;  
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you have 3 unique integers and your validation still allow 2 of them to be same?

Comment: These variable are serving as parameters to a function so i need to have default value to call the function

Comment: sorry, the desired output is not very clear. Let me understand better. Your method should modify the values of some of possibly duplicate values in order to avoid duplications, right ? Which values can be used to modify the fields ? And what is the meaning of the return value ? And what you mean for "passing validation" ?

Comment: ```return -2 ;```  it is the error code  the validation function return  so that  appropriate message can be shown. what is desired is to validate the update made to the variable  value that they shouldn't be updated to same value @Massimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As not very clear what to do with defaults, i try to post 2 options. I assume `return 0` as the validation passed return value.

If the requirement is simply to reject validation if 2 values are equal, it should be enough to have the condition

```
 if(  firstChoice==secondChoice || 
              firstChoice== thirdChoice || secondChoice==thirdChoice){
              
              return -2;
 }
 return 0;
```

indipendently from defaults.

If instead you should validate anyway all fields with value 0 and check for equality the non-0 fields, the condition can became as follows

```
 if(  (firstChoice!=0 && firstChoice==secondChoice) || 
              (firstChoice!=0 && firstChoice== thirdChoice) || (secondChoice !=0 && secondChoice==thirdChoice)){
              
              return -2;
 }
 return 0;
```

in this way fields with value 0 are validated

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
boolean isInvalid  = firstChoice!=0 ? 
(firstChoice == secondChoice ||firstChoice == thirdChoice):
(secondChoice!=0 && secondChoice==thirdChoice);

if(isInvalid) {
  return -2;
}
```

Another bug in your code, check of choice should be inclusive of 8 and 0

```
if(choice >= 8 || choice =< 0){
    return -1;
}
```